# Angular nested component declaration in html

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Is it possible to define template html like so:

```
<ipe-container>
    <ipe-artboard></ipe-artboard>    
</ipe-container>
```

in some way?

Both components are known and declared in the module where this takes place. What I see happening now is that only the ipe-container is instantiated (available in the DOM) but the ipe-artboard is nowhere to be seen. When putting this ip-artboard component un-nested it renders in the browser (DOM).

Comment: read [transclusion](https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content), it will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

In `<ipe-container>`, add `<ng-content>` in the component template. Here is an example:

```
<div>Some Content</div>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Now, anything added inside the `<ipe-container>` selector will be rendered inside the `<ng-content>`.

Read more about [**Content Projection**](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/components/content-projection/).

Comment: Thanx, works like a charm! Is this a good practice? This container is just some simple container that's placed in CSS grid layout and might be used multiple times to display different content. I want to direct the CSS layout properties from the parent component's SASS. It felt quitte natural to me to do it like this but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Its not a bad practice at all. I am also using the same approach in a project.